# SQL Server - copy data across tables , but copy the data only when it match with a specific column name

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example I got this 2 table

dbo.fc_states

```
StateId     Name
6316        Alberta
6317        British Columbia
```

and dbo.fc_Query

```
Name              StatesName          StateId
Abbotsford        Quebec              NULL
Abee              Alberta             NULL
100 Mile House    British Columbia    NULL
```

Ok pretty straightforward , how do I copy the `stateId` over from `fc_states` to `fc_Query`, but match it with the `StatesName`, let say the result would be

```
Name              StatesName            StateId
Abee              Alberta               6316
100 Mile House    British Columbia      6317
```

Thanks, and both `stateName` column type is `text`

Comment: What SQL have you tried so far?

Comment: I am doing Microsoft Sql

Comment: Also: you should **not** use `text` anymore - it's been deprecated in SQL Server 2005. Use a suitable-length `varchar(n)` column type instead - or `varchar(max)` (but **only** if you **really** need up to 2 billion characters for your string - no state I know would come even close to that....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
update fc_Query set StateId =
  (select StateId from fc_states where fc_states.Name = fc_Query.StatesName)
```

That should give you the result you're looking for.

Comment: Got this error The data types text and text are incompatible in the equal to operator. Is text and text couldnt be compared ?

Comment: @user777310 try in the parens part of the query eddie gave you:  (select convert(int, stateid) from fc_states where...    that is change 'stateid' to 'convert(int, stateid)'.  Then I think it'll work.

Comment: nvm , i cast it to varchar when comparing cast(dbo.Query.province as varchar) and solved the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a different way than what Eddie did, I like MERGE for updates if they're not dead simple (like I wouldn't consider yours dead simple).  So if you're bored/curious also try

```
WITH stateIds as
   (SELECT name, MAX(stateID) as stID
   FROM fc_states
   GROUP BY name)
MERGE fc_Query
   on stateids.name = fc_query.statesname
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
   SET fc_query.stateid = convert(int, stid)
 ;
```

The first part, from "WITH" to the GROUP BY NAME), is a CTE, that creates a table-like thing - a name 'stateIds' that is good as a table for the immediately following part of the query - where there's guaranteed to be only one row per state name.  Then the MERGE looks for anything in the fc_query with a matching name.  And if there's a match, it sets it as you want.  YOu can make a small edit if you don't want to overwrite existing stateids in fc_query:

```
WITH stateIds as
   (SELECT name, MAX(stateID) as stID
   FROM fc_states
   GROUP BY name)
MERGE fc_Query
   ON stateids.name = fc_query.statesname
   AND fc_query.statid IS NOT NULL
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
   SET fc_query.stateid = convert(int, stid)
   ;
```

And you can have it do something different to rows that don't match.  So I think MERGE is good for a lot of applications.  You need a semicolon at the end of MERGE statements, and you have to guarantee that there will only be one match or zero matches in the source (that is "stateids", my CTE) for each row in the target; if there's more than one match some horrible thing happens, Satan wins or the US economy falters, I'm not sure what, just never let it happen.

Comment: +1 for suggesting new way of doing the same thing. Although I haven't tried this, I like the effort you took in writing it and explaining it.

Comment: @shahkalpesh thanks for the vote.  I have to update lots of duplicate data exported from other systems, and I find MERGE a godsend.  To me almost every UPDATE looks like a nail to hammer with MERGE